# How to change watermark value dynamically itext pdf java

Tags: java, spring-boot, itext, itext7, watermark

```
public class WatermarkPageEvent extends PdfPageEventHelper {

    private static Font catFont = new Font(Font.FontFamily.TIMES_ROMAN, 50, Font.NORMAL, BaseColor.LIGHT_GRAY);
    String date = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy").format(new Date());

    @Override
    public void onEndPage(PdfWriter writer, Document document) {
        ColumnText.showTextAligned(writer.getDirectContentUnder(),
                Element.ALIGN_CENTER,  new Phrase(date + ",Watermark", catFont),
                307.5f,370, 45f);
    }
}
```

```
    Document document = new Document();
    ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    PdfWriter pdfWriter = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, byteArrayOutputStream);
    document.open();
    pdfWriter.setPageEvent(new WatermarkPageEvent());
```

I want to change of value of "watermark" based on some query dynamically, presently it is fixed as "Watermark".

Comment: Show your work refactoring there watermark string into a constructor parameter.

Comment: Can you explain little more,

Comment: Introduce a parameter string to the WatermarkPageEvent constructor and use that instead for the watermark.  If you need more help than that, show your efforts.

Comment: I have resolved the issue by adding a String parameter for watermark value and created a parametrized constructor to set the values. While creating the watermark object I pass the values as parameters and set the dynamic value onEndPage() method

Comment: So you refactored as suggested.  Well done.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class WatermarkPageEvent extends PdfPageEventHelper {

    private static Font catFont = new Font(Font.FontFamily.TIMES_ROMAN, 50, Font.NORMAL, BaseColor.LIGHT_GRAY);

    String date;
    String watermark;
    public WatermarkPageEvent(String date,String watermark) {
        super();
        this.date = date;
        this.watermark = watermark;
    }

    @Override
    public void onEndPage(PdfWriter writer, Document document) {
        ColumnText.showTextAligned(writer.getDirectContentUnder(),
                Element.ALIGN_CENTER,  new Phrase(date + watermark, catFont),
                307.5f,370, 45f);
    }
}
```

```
pdfWriter.setPageEvent(new WatermarkPageEvent(new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy").format(new Date()),watermark));
```